# Laravel Ajax Call to a function in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and I want to make an ajax call to a function written in controller. I have done the following but not working.

In View :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'OrderData', // Not sure what to add as URL here
    data: { id: 7 }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

My Controller which is located inside app/controllers/DashBoardController.php
and inside DashBoardController.php I have

```
class DashBoardController extends BaseController {
    public function DashView(){
        return View::make('dashboard');
    }

    public function OrderData(){ // This is the function which I want to call from ajax
        return "I am in";
    }
}
```

My Question is how can I make an ajax call from view on page load to a function inside my DashBoardController.php ?? Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this needing help, I have added an expanded tutorial as a [post on my website](http://thingsaker.com/blog/ajax-laravel-controller-method) - hope its useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `routes.php` file add

```
Route::post('/orderdata', 'DashBoardController@OrderData');
```

Then use your ajax call to send data to `/orderdata` the data will be passed through to your `OrderData` method in the `DashBoardController`

So your ajax call would become

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/orderdata', // This is what I have updated
    data: { id: 7 }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

If you want to access the data you will need to add that into your method like so

```
class DashBoardController extends BaseController {
    public function DashView(){
        return View::make('dashboard');
    }

    public function OrderData($postData){ // This is the function which I want to call from ajax
        //do something awesome with that post data 
        return "I am in";
    }
}
```

And update your route to

```
Route::post('/orderdata/{postdata}', 'DashBoardController@OrderData')
```

Comment: I did this and I am getting `404 Not Found` .. I tried this before posting this question.

Comment: Your answer did help me to find out my issue. In the ajax call you have added `url : '/orderdata'` .. Remove the slash. I did a very silly mistake though. In Routes.php I used get instead of post.

Comment: Ah ok, well glad it helped you out. I used `/` assuming your going from root. Update accordingly for your URL.

Comment: Also Can you tell me how to create a simple modal and fetch the data from database.. Any link will be useful.. thanks

Comment: Sure, I cant really describe it in the comments but if you havent already check out [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com)

Comment: I will definetely go through Laracast but I think it will take some time though. Can you just give me a small example of modal and how to fetch data from db.

Comment: Ok, couple of things to remember about laravel models. If your DB table is called `projects` your model will be `Project.php`, then use the [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) to do database calls like `Project::get()` which will get all of your projects. Thats really all I can do in comments, read the Eloquent documentation its pretty clear and very powerful. Have a go, if you get stuck ask a question on SO, I watch the laravel tags if i see it I will give you a helping hand.