# Calling a PHP method inside a controller with Ajax (Laravel)

Tags: php, angular, ajax, laravel

I have a Controller in my Laravel project called Clientecontroller, it works perfectly. Inside it, I have a method called listar() who brings me client's information.

```
public function listar(Cliente $cliente) {
    $clientes = DB::table('clientes')
        ->where('documento_id', 1)
        ->first();  

    return $clientes;
}
```

Sure it has some troubles but my main question is, how I call this listar() function from a view with Angular or Ajax or whatever could work.

I am working in a selling system and I have to bring the client information before selecting anything else. I want to write the ID number from the clients in my view and bring the client information from my controller without reloading. But I am still stuck in the processing reaching the listar() function.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**1. The classical HTML approach**

Let's say you have a button on your page :

```html
<button id="call-listar">Call !</button>
```

You could send an HTTP Request to your Laravel application like that :

```js
document.querySelector('#call-listar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Use the fetch() API to send an HTTP Request :
  fetch('/the-url-of-listar-controller')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      // Do what you want to do with the JSON
    });
});
```

You can find a very usefull documentation about the `fetch()` API here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

**2. Inside an Angular Component**

This is an other story here, let's say you have this button in your HTML Template :

```html
<button (click)="callListar()">Call !</button>
```

Inside your TypeScript, you could use HttpClientModule to send an HTTP Request to your Laravel App :

```js
class MyComponent {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  callListar() {
   this.http.get('/url-of-listar-controller')
     .subscribe(response => {
       // Do what you want with the response
     });
  }
}
```

**WARNING : HttpClientModule needed !**

You must import the HttpClientModule inside your AppModule or any other module of your Angular App where you want to use this component :

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.php file add

```
Route::post('/cliente', 'Clientecontroller@listar');
```

And now use your ajax call in order to send data to /cliente the data will be sent through to your listar method in the ClienteController.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/cliente', 
    data: { id: 7 }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

This question was answered, for more details head over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015256/laravel-ajax-call-to-a-function-in-controller)

Comment: I follow you but /cliente isn't a view, right? 'cuz I do what you say but now I have a

POST http://127.0.0.1/cliente 404 (Not Found)

error, that isn't a view of course. I am trying to load the data from listar in the current view I am.