# Update data in database without refreshing the page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

in the system that I developed using PHP framework Laravel there is a status where the status will change from active to completed if the time or date that has been set has been reached. My question is, how to make the status change without refreshing the page? can I use Laravel scheduler?

Comment: Take a look at `ajax` requests, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26015321/281278) should be of help.

Comment: "_can I use Laravel scheduler?_" Yes, you can

Comment: Needs a little more info. If the status changes in 2 days you'd need to keep the page open that long when using AJAX, or open the page around the date set. Laravel scheduler will run in the background/on the server and change the status even if no page is open.